# tcpserver won't connect over a port forward

Tags: tcp, port-forwarding

I port forwarded a computer on port 1000:
[image: RPi port forwarded]

When I run `tcpserver 0 1000 echo test` on the computer and run `nc lostxor.com 1000` on another computer, `netcat` hangs.

If I run `nc -l 1000` on the first one and run `nc lostxor.com 1000` on the other one, it successfully connects and I can send data between the two computers.

Trying to connect to `tcpserver` using the local IP works, returning `test`.

Why won't `tcpserver` connect over a port forward, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which side of the NAT was this "other computer"?  And answerers will need to know what device is doing the NAT and the port forwarding, so they stand a chance of at least guessing whether that device supports hairpin NAT.

Comment: The other computer is on the same network. The problem is definitely with `tcpserver`, since `nc -l 1000` works fine through the port forward.